# How to generate REUSE/SPDX info for a git repo

Tags: git, reusability, generate, spdx

### Intro

The [REUSE tool](https://git.fsfe.org/reuse/tool) from the [REUSE project](https://reuse.software/) by the [Free Software Foundation Europe](https://fsfe.org/)
allows to add, maintain and extract detailed copyright and licensing info on a fine-grained scale,
and it does that using a format that is both human- and machine-readable.
To me, it is excellent work they did there.

In the end though, it is statically tracked info,
mostly stored in source file header comments,
and as such, it has to be maintained, and -
most importantly for existing projects -
created.
That can be an arduous, boring task to be done by hand,
especially when one thinks that a lot of this info could be extracted from the git commit meta-data of the project.

### Question

How to reduce the manual workload in initially annotating
an already existing project with REUSE info?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [`reuseify.sh`](https://github.com/hoijui/reuseify)
BASH script for that purpose.
Next to extracting and assigning the git author info,
it also simplifies assigning licenses to groups of files using regexes.

Example usage:

```bash
cd my-git-project
reuseify.sh --init
# Manually edit file '.reuseify/license_rgxs.tsv'.
reuseify.sh
# Amend the created git commit with your favorite IDE or git GUI.
```